# Category list not working on category page - Magento

Tags: php, magento, navigation, e-commerce, categories

Firstly I am new to Magento, so please explain in detail if you can help.

I have used the following code:

```
  <div class="left-nav-inner">  
    <h3 id="products">Products</h3>
    <h4>Shop by:</h4>
    <ul id="product-menu">

<?php
/* Get the categories that are active for the store */
$_main_categories=$this->getStoreCategories();

/* Get the current category the user is in */
$_current_category=$this->getCurrentCategory();

/* Get the current category path */
$_categorypath = $this->getCurrentCategoryPath();
?>
<?php
if ($_main_categories):
    /* This bit cycles through the categories - setting the next one to current */
    foreach ($_main_categories as $_main_category):
      if($_main_category->getIsActive()):                             
           $cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_main_category->getId());
           $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
           $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);     

/* Write the main categories */           
?>                
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getUrl()?>"><?php echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();?></a></li>   


<?php 

/* Check the category variable loop against the current category path if it is - print sub categories */
if (in_array($this->getCurrentCategory()->getId(), $_categorypath)): ?>
<?php $_maincategorylisting=$this->getCurrentCategory()?>                        
<?php $_categories=$this->getCurrentChildCategories()?>
<?php if($_categories->count()):?>


<?php /* This resets the category back to the original pages category
****     If this is not done, subsequent calls on the same page will use the last category
****    in the foreach loop
*/   ?>
<?php $layer->setCurrentCategory($_current_category);  ?> 
<?php endif; ?>   

<?php endif; ?>                                   

<?php         
endif;
endforeach; 
else:
?>
<p>$_main_categories array was empty.</p>
<p>This might be because you are referencing this phtml file with a wrong type attribute. You should use <block type="catalog/navigation" ... /> !</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This displays listings on my left menu as required however when I click the category urls the category page will not show the products..

I can get the products to show if I remove the left column within:

app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalog.xml

I did this with the following code:

---

Category default layout

---

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    <remove name="left" />
```

As you can see I added the 'remove name=left'.

I need to have the left menu with the categories displaying on every page of the website and I need the products to show up when I click on the categories...

Please help.

Comment: what displays on the target URL?  Do you get the standard header/footer and no content?  Do you get the category title and cms block and no product listing?  Have you checked that logging is on and for entries in system.log and/or exception.log?

Comment: I am getting everything except the products. Category title is displaying correctly, along with breadcrumb etc. It works fine showing all products when I don't use the left nav. So something in the category list code is throwing it off i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the `</ul>` tag after your `endforeach`.

Take a look in your html source. You may find that everything is in the page, just nested inside the `<ul>` tag, so it doesn't get rendered by the browser.

If I'm right, This ought to show things up for you (notice the `</ul>` tag near the end):

```
 <div class="left-nav-inner">  
    <h3 id="products">Products</h3>
    <h4>Shop by:</h4>
    <ul id="product-menu">

<?php
/* Get the categories that are active for the store */
$_main_categories=$this->getStoreCategories();

/* Get the current category the user is in */
$_current_category=$this->getCurrentCategory();

/* Get the current category path */
$_categorypath = $this->getCurrentCategoryPath();
?>
<?php
if ($_main_categories):
    /* This bit cycles through the categories - setting the next one to current */
    foreach ($_main_categories as $_main_category):
      if($_main_category->getIsActive()):                             
           $cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_main_category->getId());
           $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
           $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);     

/* Write the main categories */           
?>                
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getUrl()?>"><?php echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();?></a></li>   


<?php 

/* Check the category variable loop against the current category path if it is - print sub categories */
if (in_array($this->getCurrentCategory()->getId(), $_categorypath)): ?>
<?php $_maincategorylisting=$this->getCurrentCategory()?>                        
<?php $_categories=$this->getCurrentChildCategories()?>
<?php if($_categories->count()):?>


<?php /* This resets the category back to the original pages category
****     If this is not done, subsequent calls on the same page will use the last category
****    in the foreach loop
*/   ?>
<?php $layer->setCurrentCategory($_current_category);  ?> 
<?php endif; ?>   

<?php endif; ?>                                   

<?php         
endif;
endforeach; 
?>
</ul><!-- See what I did here? -->
<?php
else:
?>

<p>$_main_categories array was empty.</p>
<p>This might be because you are referencing this phtml file with a wrong type attribute. You should use <block type="catalog/navigation" ... /> !</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use Alan Storm's Layoutviewer to debug what's happening on your target url.  You can download it from [this article](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates), note that you will need to create your own module declaration xml to insert into `app/etc/modules` for the module to be activated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Admin ->cms->pages->home page->design->custom design ->Add** this code

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
</reference>
```